# Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference

Tags: angularjs

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null
>   reference.
>
> prefixfree.min.js (5,288)

Answer (score 0):

1. `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="newStyle.css" />`
2. `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="newStyle.css" />`

the first one is valid but the second inclusion throws script exception of the above.